# Why wont this loop?

Tags: python, sql, mariadb

Newby working my way through python and sql with mariadb.
Why wont this loop?  It updates the first record only. Im pretty hack at this...

```
cursor1.execute("select recordid, mvavgvol, quote_usd_volume_change_24h from pumped")
records = cursor1.fetchall()

for x in records:

            rid = (x[0])
            m = (x[1])
            o = (x[2])

            if (m >= o):
                  result = 0
            else:
                  result = 1

upd_data=(result,rid)
sql1 = ("UPDATE pumped SET mvavgvolcheck = %s WHERE recordid = %s")
cursor2.execute(sql1,upd_data)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: It loops, but your update is outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are fetching multiple rows you have to store the fetched values in an array and use cursor's `executemany()` method instead.

✂

```
data= []
for x in records:
            rid = (x[0])
            result= int(x[1] > x[2])
            data+= [(result, rid)]

cursor.executemany(UPDATE pumped SET  mvavgvolcheck = %s WHERE recordid = %s", data);
```

✂

When using mariadb python module (MariaDB Connector/Python) this is much more effective since it reduces network traffic: instead of sending n update commands in a loop (where n is the number of rows in table pumped) only one command will be send to the server.

Comment: Actually not following this logic.  How does result= int(x[1] > x[2]) return a 1 or 0.  I need to test the two values and return 1 if mvavgvol < quote_usd_volume_change_24h

Comment: 5 > 2  will return True, int(5 > 2) will convert boolean to int, so result is 1 (or 0 if condition is false)

Comment: If your question was answered, mark it as answered, if you have another question file a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
conn = msql.connect(host=Host,port=Port, user=User, password=Password, database=database)
cursor1 = conn.cursor()
cursor2 = conn.cursor()

cursor1.execute("select recordid, mvavgvol, quote_usd_volume_change_24h from pumped")
records = cursor1.fetchall()

for x in records:

            rid = (x[0])
            m = (x[1])
            o = (x[2])

            if (m >= o):
                  result = 0
                  cursor2.execute("UPDATE pumped SET mvavgvolcheck = %s WHERE recordid = %s",(result, rid))
                  conn.commit()

            else:
                  result = 1
                  cursor2.execute("UPDATE pumped SET mvavgvolcheck = %s WHERE recordid = %s",(result, rid))
                  conn.commit()
```

Comment: Note that both your queries are the same. They don't need to be in the `if..else`; one query *after* it is fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).